# Filezilla не качает большой файл с первого раза. Filezilla глючит от мышки

Tags: filezilla

Первая ошибка у меня возникает, когда я пытаюсь прокатить мышкой, что бы выделить, допустим 5-ти файлов из 8-ми на стороне сервера.
Выделяются все, а мышку выбрасывает за пределы вправо-вверх.

Вторая ошибка при копировании нескольких файлов на сервер. Один самый большой, всегда не копируется с 1-го раза. Только со 2-го, после перезапуска **filezilla**. Как вы избегаете этих ошибок? Может нужна какая-то настройка?

[по ссылке короткий ролик, демонстрирующий две описанные ошибки](http://webhelp.kiev.ua/filezilla-bags.webm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В **FileZilla** необходимо выделять <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>. А большими файлами она всегда глючит. Может быть на `Pro` версии это исправлено. На **Ubuntu 18.04** периодически вылетает.

> UPD
>   В версии 3.40.0 работает любое выделение (соответственно и <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).